# What does it mean SELECT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM favoritelist WHERE id=:id)

Tags: mysql, sql, database, sqlite, android-studio

What is the meaning of `SELECT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM favoritelist WHERE id=:id)` in:

```
@Query("SELECT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM favoritelist WHERE id=:id)")
public int  isFavorite(int id);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM favoritelist WHERE id=:id)
```

The `exists` condition evaluates whether at least one row exists in `favoritelist` where `id` matches the given parameter. The outer query evaluates the condition in numeric context, and returns `1` if the condition is satisfied, else `0`.

In a nutshell:

- if at least one record exists in `favoritelist` whose `id` matches the parameter, the query returns `1`
- else, it returns `0`

Answer (score 1):

The SQL code is a query that returns true or false depending on wether an element with the id equal to `:id` (this is a paremter that needs to be bound when executing the query) exists in the table "favoritelist" or not.

Here it is used in an [@Query annotation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/persistence/room/Query) and specifies an SQL query that is run when the method `isFavorite` is called - the `id` parameter of the method is bound to the `:id` parameter in the query.